# Update only part pf Jenkins job using JobDSL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

There's no problem to create some template jobDSL job which will be uses for create new job basis. Generated jobs will be supplemented.
But if I want to update the template and update all generated jobs my additions will be removed.
How can I use jobDSL to update only some parts of existing jobs?

Comment: I don't think this can be done - the DSL plugin replaces the entire job definition.  There is no mixin-style DSL.

Comment: After 6 years could you solve your problem?